# Is a section of music harmonically closed if the vi or IV chord is used instead of I?

Tags: musical-forms

If I have a phrase that ends on 1^ in the melody but instead of using the I chord I use vi or IV, would the section be harmonically closed? It is not the same as ending the melody on ^2 or ^5 over a dominant chord where that is certainly open but it is also not the same as ending on the I chord so how would this be labelled. A semi-closed section?  In some of my own music a phrase may come to rest on ^1 and I even sometimes end pieces of music on the IV chord instead of the I chord because I like the way that sounds so I don't really consider this to be an "open" phrase where the music should continue.

Answer (score 1):

'Harmonically closed' means ending on the tonic chord.

You are at liberty to like the effect of ending a piece 'harmonically open', i.e. NOT on the tonic chord.

But that doesn't change the meaning of 'harmonically closed'.

Comment: My argument is that maybe the term "harmonically closed" should be extended since ending on IV or vi with ^1 in the melody is not really "open" sounding. There is some degree of stability when the the melody does conclude on ^1 even when the tonic chord is not used.

Comment: @armani And it's pleasant (and not all that uncommon) to end on VImaj7 or III.   But shall we allow 'harmonically closed' to retain its meaning, while agreeing that other endings are possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially talking about *cadences*. Perfect and plagal cadences will end on chord I - and it matters not what the melody note is, although it's usually ^1, ^3, or ^5. That's *harmonically closed*.

The opposite, unsurprisingly, is *harmonically open*, where the usual cadence is imperfect, so ending on V. Very unusual for that to accompany ^1 in the melody.

Comment: Does harmonically closed only refer to cadences? Surely the same principle is used for how a phrase ends in a piece of music? Or is it supposed that all phrases end with a cadence?

Comment: @armani - It's my belief that phrases will end with a cadence. No doubt someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can define a phrase as ‘a section of music ending on a cadence’.  Or you can define it more loosely, perhaps as ‘a section lasting until the music takes a breath (literally or figuratively)’.   If you insist on the first definition, a lot of music will have either no phrases at all, or very long ones!.